# emacs ansi-term is very slow

Tags: linux, ubuntu, emacs

I'm running emacs GNU Emacs 24.2.50.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.10) on Ubuntu 12.04.

When I open an ansi-term (or term or multi-term) buffer, and use it for a few minutes, it starts to slow way down - there is a noticeable lag when typing characters.

I then open my *Messages* buffer and see this output:

```
Invalid face attribute :foreground nil
Invalid face attribute :background nil [6 times]
Invalid face attribute :foreground nil
Invalid face attribute :background nil [5 times]
Invalid face attribute :foreground nil
Invalid face attribute :background nil
Invalid face attribute :foreground nil
Invalid face attribute :background nil
```

(there are thousands of these invalid face attribute entries)

If I downgrade to emacs 24.0.* I don't see this issue.

Any thoughts on this issue are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this happen if you change the color theme to something else?

Comment: Yes. I cleared my .emacs file - I get this problem in a completely vanilla emacs environment. If I apply a color theme, I get the same message.

Comment: A bit more information: I noticed that my .bashrc includes this alias: alias ls='ls --color=auto' . when I comment out all lines that relate to coloring the terminal text, the ansi-term error goes away.

Comment: If you find a problem in the development-version of Emacs (or any other package, for that matter) report it to the developers so they can fix it.  I.e. `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Good idea. I didn't realize that 24.2.50.1 was a development version. I just compiled GNU Emacs 24.2.1 and the problem appears to be resolved. Thank you.